# Stream music to multiple Bluetooth speakers simultaneously

Tags: bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I am looking to take my music playlist, and stream it (For lack of a better term) to multiple Bluetooth speakers at once. I have tried many, many ways, but nothing has worked. I just want a simple (If one could call it that) system that takes my playlist, and broadcasts it to multiple speakers.

What I have (Just listing things I have that can be used, obviously I need to use the speakers)

- 2 Bluetooth Speakers (NOT Bluetooth 5. One speaker can be Bluetooth OR AUX, while the other must be Bluetooth. I don't care what combo is used as long as it works.)
- 1 iPhone SE 2020
- 1 iPad Mini 5 (And an iPad mini 3 or 4 (I forget))
- 2 Windows 10 PC’s (7 years old and less than a year old)
- 1 Raspberry Pi 4
- 5 Raspberry Pi Pico’s (Don’t think it can do things with audio, but listing anyway)
- 5 Google Home devices (Plus one Chromecast)
- A YoutubeMusic premium subscription

What I tried:

- AmpMe - Too expensive
- Rave - Don’t Work/lag
- eBeats - Don’t Work/lag
- EarBuds - Don’t Work/lag
- Google Home devices in speaker groups with default speakers set as my Bluetooth ones - WAY too much lag (The Google Home App audio delay adjuster doesn't work either)

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.bluetooth.com/media/le-audio/le-audio-faqs/#broadcast

> While Bluetooth supports multiple communication topologies for data
> transfer, including point-to-point, broadcast and mesh, it has only
> supported point-to-point communications for audio. LE Audio changes
> that with Broadcast Audio, a new feature that enables an audio source
> device to broadcast an audio stream to an unlimited number of
> Bluetooth audio sink devices.

It would seem that what you are asking for is in the new LE Audio functionality that is not widely available yet.

Comment: Ok, I Didn't ever know that existed. Is there any way I can connect multiple of my devices together and have each one connected to a Bluetooth speaker as well?